# Match names in the format of "A - B", but NOT in the format of "A - B: Total goals - odd or even"

Tags: c#, .net, regex, visual-studio

Hi I met a problem when processing the match names of sports, the principle is this:

1. match strings with format of "A - B"
2. NOT match strings with any ":" after "A - B", eg "A - B: Total goals - odd or even"

---

Here is my **Regex**:
**^.+(\s+-\s+)([^:\n]+)(?!:[\w\s]+)$**

---

And here are some example strings **Should Match:**

Mattek-Sands Bethanie - Safarova Lucie

L. Hewitt - O. Rochus

Ball Carsten - S. Darcis

Poland - Austria

Poland - Austria   1x2

Poland - Austria   1 x 2

Poland - Austria 1x2

Poland - Austria - 1x2

Poland - Austria _ 1x2

Poland - Austria (1x2)

---

Here are some example strings **Should NOT Match:**

Vityaz Podolsk Chekhov - Traktor Chel: Total goals - odd or even

Haka - JJK: Half time

Lyngby - AaB: Draw No Bet

AC Horsens - FC Midtjylland: First team to score

Mattek-Sands Bethanie - Safarova Lucie: Who will win set number 1?

Czech Republic - Kazakhstan: 1x2

Romania - Slovak Republic: 1x2

Norway - Moldova: 1x2

Yushin Okami - Mark Munoz<BR/><span>UFC on VERSUS 2</span>: 1x2

Thiago Alves - Jon Fitch<BR/><span>UFC 117 - Oakland</span>: 1x2

Poland - Austria: 1x2

Poland - Austria: 1 x 2

---

BUT the problem is my regex **MATCHES** the first string in the **Shoud NOT Match** category:

"Vityaz Podolsk Chekhov - Traktor Chel: Total goals - odd or even"

And if I delete the "-" after the ":", it will NOT MATCH any more, which is good.

I think the problem might be the (\s+-\s+) part in the Regex, but I couldn't actually figure out how to fix it.

Would anyone one help? Thx!

Comment: Not a regex expert, but I *think* the problem is that `+` is greedy. Perhaps change it to `+?` and see what happens. On the other hand, you *could* also initially check `IndexOf(":")` and reject it immediately.

Answer (score 0):

You can just remove `(?!:[\w\s]+)` and use:

```
^.+?(\s+-\s+)([^:\n]+)$
```

After the `-`, this will match every character that isn't a `:` and guarantee that it matches all the way to the end of the string/line.

Comment: Anthony made a good point about the greedy `+` as well. `+?` will make it lazy.

Comment: This will match the first one of his "don't match these" lines (because it contains another ` - ` after the `:`).

Answer (score 0):

I suggest

```
^([^:]+)\s+-\s+([^:]+)$
```

This matches a string that contains

1. any number of characters except `:`, followed by
2. whitespace, `-`, whitespace, followed by
3. any number of characters except `:`.

The `^` and `$` anchors make sure that the entire string is matched. A string that contains a `:` can thus never match, and thus the regex will fail in all your negative example cases and match all you positive example cases.

I have also enclosed the first and second parts of the match in capturing parentheses in case you want to do something with them later; and I have removed the unnecessary parens around the `\s+-\s+` bit.